# Laravel Project "{"error":"Resource item not found."}"

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to update a field in the database but I get this error

```
"{"error":"Resource item not found."}"
```

below is my update code

```
 public function update(Request $request, $merchant_id)
    {
        // Validation for required fields (and using some regex to validate our numeric value)
        $request->validate([
            'fees'=>'required',
    
        ]); 
        $merchants = Merchants_data::find($merchant_id);
        $merchants->fees =  $request->get('fees');
        $merchants->save();
 
        return redirect('/manage_merchants')->with('success', 'Transaction Fee updated.'); // -> resources/views/stocks/index.blade.php
    }
```

below is my route

```
Route::patch('update_merchant/{merchant_id}', 'MerchantsController@update')->name('update');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but can you tell us what exact error occurred does it not  entered inside the controller or not ??.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Resource item not found" indicates that the database query in the update() method was not able to find the resource with the specified $merchant_id.
Check if you have a $merchant_id with that value in your database

Comment: iT is there in the database, I am updating it on button click on the front end, I can even capture the value in the form, but I cant update it

Answer (score 0):

Can you first trying this :

```
 public function update(Request $request, $merchant_id)
{
    dd($request, $merchant_id);

}
```

And tell me what you got.
My first idea is that you got 2 parameters here, but only one in your route.
I'm not sure that you can retrieve $request and $merchant_id in your function.